# Data corrupted Buffer to BLOB MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, nginx

With NodeJs, I try to upload a buffer (image) in my MySQL LONGBLOB sent by a POST of my application , i receive it perfecly in my script, but when I insert it in my table, I dont have the same data than what i had.

Can you explain me why ?

```js
var query = "INSERT INTO categorie (nom_categorie";

// FIELD
if (req.body.def_categorie) query += ",def_categorie";
if (req.body.idplat) query += ",idplat";
if (req.body.idmenu) query += ",idmenu";
if (req.body.image_categorie) query += ",image_categorie";

query += ")";

query += " VALUES (" + pool.escape(req.body.nom_categorie);

// VALUES (Echappement des caractères pour empécher les injections SQL
if (req.body.def_categorie) query += "," + pool.escape(req.body.def_categorie);
if (req.body.idplat) query += "," + pool.escape(req.body.idplat);
if (req.body.idmenu) query += "," + pool.escape(req.body.idmenu);
if (req.body.image_categorie) query += "," + Buffer.from(req.body.image_categorie, "utf8");

query += ")";

pool.query(query, null, function (err, results) {
  if (err) {
    pool.end();
    res.status(500).send(err);
  } else {
    pool.end();
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.send(results);
  }
});
```

File i send :[image: File Sent]

File in my DB : [image: File DB]

Comment: Could be just an encoding issue when you're visualising it. When you extract the file from your DB, can you create a valid PNG from it?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, no I can't, i tried to translate it in hexadical, all special caracter are differents ...

Comment: You should use parametrized queries instead of composing them using `pool.escape()`. That way you can let the database driver also do the right thing with BLOBs, which is your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, i just encode my data in BASE64 and i encode it again with an URLENCODE

Comment: That's not a good solution. You're now using a BLOB (binary) column to store text data.

Comment: So how can i do ?